# They feel a lack of purpose

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct?

> After returement, some people feel lonely, and also they feel a lack of purpose in life.

Does the use of ‘a lack’ after ‘feel’ correct? And if not, how could I write the sentence correctly to have the same meaning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong but you might also rephrase it as:

> After retirement, some people feel lonely and some might experience a
>   lack of purpose in life.

Answer (score 1):

To feel a lack of purpose is 100% idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is valid. From what I can glean from your question, your confusion stems from "feeling a lack", with a lack being a void or negation or absence. How can one feel an absence?

However, one can feel (or perceive) a lack. For example, "feeling cold" means to feel a lack of heat, in the same way that "feeling hot" means to feel an excess of heat.

Or to use an example from your sentence, "feeling lonely" is also feeling a lack, specifically a lack of companionship or community.

If you would like to rewrite the sentence, I would suggest:

> After returement, some people feel lonely and without a purpose in life.

although KeykoYume's suggestion would also work.